What is the equivalent of JBoss EAP 6.4's <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" ...> in JBoss EAP 8.0?
I have two similar war files that I'd like to deploy simultaneously.  Based of the answer to this question, I was able to deploy the wars on JBoss EAP 6.4, and they worked as expected.  Some of the important things I had to do included defining connectors and virtual-servers in standalone.xml, which I did like so:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <!-- 2 connector specifications that reference virtual-servers -->
    <!-- 2 virtual-server specifications -->
</subsystem>

We decided to move to JBoss EAP 8.0, which required many changes.  The changes I made to standalone.xml appear to be illegal now.  When I start JBoss, I get the following error:
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)

OPVDX001: Validation error in standalone.xml -----------------------------------
|
|  545:         <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
|                                                                                                                ^^^^ Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2}subsystem'
                      (less interesting stuff omitted)
|
| The primary underlying error message was:
| > ParseError at [row,col]:[545,106]
| > Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2}subsystem'
|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'm most interested in how to solve my immediate problem, which is how to run our two wars simultaneously without conflict.  A closely related question is how does one know what are valid subsystems in JBoss EAP 8.0, and how do I specify those subsystems in XML (or otherwise)?  The only reason I made the changes to standalone.xml in the first place was because I came across the StackOverflow question in a Google search.  I have yet to find the JBoss documentation that might have led me to that solution, although I suspect it exists somewhere.
